# How do I program the Sparkfun Arduino Pro Micro with Linux?

Tags: linux, drivers, compatibility, arduino

Sparkfun's [Arduino Pro Micro](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/11098) was the ideal choice for me (in size and price), but I cannot figure out how to program it on anything other than Windows. Sparkfun doesn't provide any resources on how to program the Arduino Pro Micro on Linux, and there aren't any direct resources on the Internet for installing drivers/ programming it. Hoow do I program the Arduino Pro Micro with Linux?
Thanks!

*Note: My OS is Ubuntu*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[It seems like it is programmable with classic arduino IDE](https://github.com/sparkfun/SF32u4_boards) if [you add some stuff on it](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/wiki/Arduino-IDE-1.5---3rd-party-Hardware-specification)